# Proposing new tag on SO for Winpython distribution

Tags: discussion, tags

When searching on SO for '[winpython](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=winpython)', there are currently 199 results, 13 for this month (20 days) mentioning winython.

As [Winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) is a very widespread python-distribution for Windows in the scientific area it would be great to have all these topics in a tag to consolidate them, also making it easy to follow them.

I'm not sure if this is the right place, but it has been proposed in the SO-chat.

As requested, some links to questions appropriate to this tag:

- [Install github clones of a python package to WinPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194079/install-github-clones-of-a-python-package-to-winpython)
- [Using windows winpython with cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353483/using-windows-winpython-with-cygwin)
- [Problems with numpy in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815567/problems-with-numpy-in-pycharm)
- [Spyder autocomplete doesn't work with 64-bit WinPython 2.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316459/spyder-autocomplete-doesnt-work-with-64-bit-winpython-2-7-5)
- [Setting python path for WinPython to use f2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146050/setting-python-path-for-winpython-to-use-f2py)
- [how can I update scipy in winpython on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260487/how-can-i-update-scipy-in-winpython-on-windows)
- [How to exit a script in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928377/how-to-exit-a-script-in-spyder)
- [PythonXY compiles differently than WinPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921417/pythonxy-compiles-differently-than-winpython)

Comment: The search includes answers; there are [138 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=winpython+is%3Aq), 7 in September.

Comment: Such a tag should only be used for problems *unique to WinPython* however; for the most part WinPython looks like it is just a bundling of already tagged Python components.

Comment: Pick out a handful of questions deserving that tag (the problem should be winpython-specific like martin says), add them to the request, and someone will shortly add the tag. Superficial scanning of a few questions your search produced failed to yield me a good candidate.